# When using the Reindex API to move data from one index to another, can I use a script to detect if a matching doc exists and do a partial update?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have two distinct indexes in Elasticsearch and I'm trying to combine some of the data from both indexes into a new index. I'd like to use the Reindex API rather than scrolling through results and bulk loading. The catch is some of the data may be duplicated in both indexes.

Ideally I'd like to dump all the matching data form one index first using Reindex and then follow up with another Reindex from the second index.  If during the second Reindex a matching id is found, update one value on the doc in the destination index, otherwise create a new doc. Is this possible with a script? It can't find a way to read the data on the destination index during the process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible with only the Reindex API, which only supports the following two different semantics via [the `op_type` parameter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html#docs-reindex-api-request-body):

- `op_type: index`: (default) overrides the document no matter what
- `op_type: create`: only create the document if it not already exists

But there is no "update" semantics.

However, there's one way to achieve what you need using a combination of the [enrich processor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/enrich-setup.html) and the Reindex API. The idea is to pick one index (usually the smaller, but it can be either, in your case it would be the second one) and to build an enrich index out of it keyed on the document id. That enrich index can then be used in an ingest pipeline when reindexing the first index into the target one to update the target index. [It goes like this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/match-enrich-policy-type.html):

First, create an enrich policy based out of the second index:

```
PUT /_enrich/policy/second-index-policy
{
  "match": {
    "indices": "second-index",
    "match_field": "id_field",
    "enrich_fields": ["update_field"]
  }
}
```

Then you need to execute that policy in order to build the enrich index:

```
PUT /_enrich/policy/second-index-policy/_execute
```

This call won't return, so if your index size is substantial, the odds are high that the call will time out, but the enrich process will continue running in the background. In this case, you can follow the process using either of the following two commands:

```
GET /_enrich/_stats
```

or

```
GET _tasks?actions=policy*&detailed
```

Once this is done, you can build your enrich pipeline:

```
PUT /_ingest/pipeline/second_index_lookup
{
  "processors" : [
    {
      "enrich" : {
        "description": "Update data from the second index",
        "policy_name": "second-index-policy",
        "field" : "id_field",
        "target_field": "target_field"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

You're now ready to reindex the first index into the target index **and** enrich it with the data from the second index on-the-go. Using the Reindex API you can specify the above [pipeline in the `dest` section](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html#reindex-with-an-ingest-pipeline), like this:

```
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "first_index"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "target_index",
    "pipeline": "second_index_lookup"
  }
}
```

Once this is done, there's only one thing remaining to do, i.e. reindex the second index into the target index with `op_type: create` semantics, so that you only create documents that were not available in the first index. It goes like this:

```
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "second_index"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "target_index",
    "op_type": "create"
  }
}
```

Voilà!! Try it out and let us know how it goes!

Comment: Wow. Thanks for taking the time to write this detailed answer. I've tried the enrich processor before but not in this context. I will give that a shot. Thanks!