# Elasticsearch 7.13 populating(enrich) index with matching field values from another index

Tags: elasticsearch

I will write my question as is;

There are two indices under your cluster;
earthquakes and magnitude_type

lets say earthquakes index has bunch of fields and a "MagnitudeType"
magnitude_type index has "MagnitudeType" and "MagnitudeTypeDesc"

you want to create a new index named my_index;
my_index should have all the documents from earthquakes, we will add "MagnitudeTypeDesc" field to my_index and then populate it according to magnitude_type index where "MagnitudeType" field matches.

How can one do this?

Thanks

UPDATE!!!!

I used Val's suggestion as below,

```
PUT /_enrich/policy/second-index-policy
{
"match": {
  "indices": "magnitude_type",
   "match_field": "MagnitudeType",
   "enrich_fields": ["MagnitudeTypeDesc"]
 }
}
PUT /_enrich/policy/second-index-policy/_execute

PUT /_ingest/pipeline/second_index_lookup
{
 "processors" : [
   {
     "enrich" : {
       "description": "Update data from the second index",
       "policy_name": "second-index-policy",
       "field" : "MagnitudeType",
       "target_field": "MagnitudeType"
  }
}
]
}

POST _reindex
{
 "source": {
   "index": "earthquakes"
},
 "dest": {
  "index": "new_index",
  "pipeline": "second_index_lookup"
}
}
```

when i do this, id writes both fields to MagnitudeType. my _source looks like this what am i doing wrong?

"_source" : {
"MagnitudeType" : {
"MagnitudeType" : "MW",
"MagnitudeTypeDesc" : "cok fena zelzele"
},
"name" : "can"
}

Comment: This thread might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68028917/4604579 (hint: enrich processor)

Comment: Hello Val, I have tried your suggestion, I can populate the MagnitudeTypeDesc field in my_index but after that I cannot reindex earthquakes into it. When I first reindex earthquakes in new_index and then reindex magnitude_type it gets rid of the fields which comes from earthquakes. Any suggestions?

Comment: I suggest you update your question with a full reproduction of what you tried, so it's easier to see if there's a mistake somewhere. Thanks

Comment: I've updated as you asked hope it makes stuff clear, new_index have the MagnitudeTypeDesc field. the reindexing writes both fields from the policy under it. Instead i want to see all earthquakes fields and MagnitudeType, MagnitudeTypeDesc seperately indexed.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Can you show what you expect instead?

Comment: I want to see name, MagnitudeTypeDesc and MagnitudeType fields in new_index and they shouldn't be objects thats my problem.  
  

earthquakes has name and MagnitudeType fields. 
magnitude_type has MagnitudeType and MagnitudeTypeDesc fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did everything right by mimicking what [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68028917/4604579) advocates for, i.e. using an `enrich` processor to join data from the `magnitude_type` index into the `new_index`.

Now you simply need to flatten down the matched magnitude object using another processor called `rename` and also `remove` the temporary result object from the enrich processor, like this:

```
PUT /_ingest/pipeline/second_index_lookup
{
 "processors" : [
   {
     "enrich" : {
       "description": "Update data from the second index",
       "policy_name": "second-index-policy",
       "field" : "MagnitudeType",
       "target_field": "tmp"
     }
   },
   {
     "rename": {
       "field": "tmp.MagnitudeType",
       "target_field": "MagnitudeType"
     }
   },
   {
     "rename": {
       "field": "tmp. MagnitudeTypeDesc",
       "target_field": "MagnitudeTypeDesc"
     }
   },
   {
     "remove": {
       "field": "tmp"
     }
   }
 ]
}
```

After that, your source should look like this:

```
{ 
   "MagnitudeType" : "MW", 
   "MagnitudeTypeDesc" : "cok fena zelzele",
   "name" : "can" 
}
```