# Access index with Elastic Painless in ingest processor

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless

How can I access a specified Elastic index with Painless from an ingest processor? I haven't been able to find information on this.

Can this then also be tested from Painless Lab in Kibana?

I'm using Elastic 7.12.

Comment: You mean from a document about to be indexed in index A access data from another index B? If yes, then the enrich processor is the way. More info here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69046807/4604579

Comment: @Val Yes, that's right. Does that mean that a script cannot directly access data already stored in some other index? So in order to do more complex enrichment that cannot be done with a enrich processor, such as filtering, I need to add the data from the enrich index to the document first and then process that data into the desired shape with a script?

Comment: Yes, that's correct, you cannot access the data from another index directly, the only way is to build an enrich index that you can access from the ingest pipeline.

Comment: @Val Do you mean by that that a script processor in an ingest pipeline can access an enrich index?

Comment: Yes, the enrich processor will retrieve a matching record (or set thereof) that you can then manipulate with the subsequent processors (script or otherwise)